# Previous months latest date

Tags: sql

I have a column which contain dates of transactions occurred on working days. I am trying to group my customers to see their end of month totals for the last number of months.

Essentially, how do I get the max date for each of the last 6 months in SQL?

Example table below

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 610 | 11/30/2021 |
| 610 | 11/29/2021 |
| 610 | 11/28/2021 |
| 610 | 10/29/2021 |
| 610 | 10/15/2021 |
| 610 | 9/15/2021 |
| 610 | 9/14/2021 |
| 610 | 8/10/2021 |
| 725 | 11/30/2021 |
| 725 | 11/29/2021 |
| 725 | 11/28/2021 |
| 725 | 10/29/2021 |
| 725 | 10/15/2021 |
| 725 | 9/15/2021 |
| 725 | 9/14/2021 |
| 725 | 8/10/2021 |

what I would like to return is the table below

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 610 | 11/30/2021 |
| 610 | 10/15/2021 |
| 610 | 9/15/2021 |
| 610 | 8/10/2021 |
| 725 | 11/30/2021 |
| 725 | 10/29/2021 |
| 725 | 9/15/2021 |
| 725 | 8/10/2021 |

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column ?

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Comment: In the expected result you have made a mistake..According to your expectation the date will be 10/29/2021. But you mentioned 10/15/2021

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate and group by the YEAR and MONTH of your date column in a subquery to get the MAX date per month (and year), then do not return the year and month in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed the table name as **Test** and first column as **Code** and Second column name as **TransactionDate**. I have implemented my query in SQL SERVER.

```
SELECT Code, FORMAT (Max(TransactionDate), 'dd/MM/yyyy ') 
FROM Test
GROUP By Code, MONTH(TransactionDate), YEAR(TransactionDate)
ORDER By Code ASC, Max(TransactionDate) DESC
```

You can check my query in SQL Fiddle. [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15e123/5)